# How to apply user-defined assembly files to the `make` process

Tags: c++, assembly, makefile, compilation

assembly file is a intermediate product of `make` process.
I want to edit assembly files, and apply this assembly file(*.s) to the process of make.

Make process is like below.

1. generate `*.ii` from the `*.cpp` files.
2. generate `*.s` from the `*.ii` files.
3. assemble `*.o` from the `*.s` files.
4. Finally, linker links `*.o` files to and generate the final binaries.

**What I want to do:**

Modify the assembly files (*.s files) after `step 2`.
Then modified assembly files to be reflected in the next step of make.

**What I tried:**

I copied the modified assembly file to target directory typed `make all`.
But modified assembly file didn't reflected in the result binary because `make process` re-generate assembly file inside target directory.

Is there a way to apply user-defined assembly files into the `make` process?

Comment: Don't edit the files in-place, rename them. Then update your rules to reflect that.

Comment: Are you using a makefile? Please add it to your question if you are or confirm that you're not using one.

Comment: The project I am using is Microsoft Chakracore. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore

I want to modify some of assembly files among Chakracore's libraries, 
and apply them in the process of compile.

Comment: There is a faint smell of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. *My* first question would have been "How do I get the compiler to generate the code I need?".

Comment: you can set up your make rules in such way, that `c` files will be only turned into -> "ii" -> "s" into some target directory, then the final chain to turn "s" -> "o" -> binary will expect the "s" files in other directory, so the build of binary will fail (producing only original "s"), then you can modify them and copy into the new source directory where the rules for "s" -> "o" -> binary will find them. This is usually simple to do with your own Makefile + project, where you know how it evolved, and you understand your Makefile rules. May be lot more tricky with 3rd party project. And +1 Bo.

Comment: Usually the idea of modifying the "s" files of such project as ChakraCore sounds like really wrong idea, especially manual modification, but even automated one. It's like asking for lot more trouble somewhere later in the line, or the change is so trivial, that you can achieve it on the C level maybe.